# Is it normal to be able to hear a high pitch buzz from devices that are charging?

Tags: battery-charging, frequency, charger, charging

I have noticed that in ungrounded outlets I am able to hear an almost silent high pitch sound if I plug in earphones into the device being charged.

I think this is the 50 Hz electrical signal that I'm hearing.

I can also hear this when a device is not charging but touching a cable that is charging another device.

Also the noise goes away when I touch the device. I assume this is because of me providing the grounding.

Is this a normal thing? Would it reduce the lifespan of the device in any way?

Comment: 50 Hz is not high pitch.

Comment: Most likely you are hearing a switch mode supply.

Comment: @Oldfart Seems like it could be it

Comment: @HarrySvensson Makes sense, the sound seems coming from the device itself so could be some component in the device or the transformed current from the charger

Answer (score 2):

50Hz is *really* low audio frequency. High pitch noise (above 10kHz usually) is coming from cheap switching power supplies. Normally designers try to use higher frequencies (outside audio range) to avoid this annoyance or mechanically dampen it (e.g. gluing), but cheap supply designers... well, don't care. [Here is wiki article about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetically_excited_acoustic_noise_and_vibration).

As for lifespan - any kind of vibration affects mechanical durability. In this case you probably have higher chances of some other cheap component crapping out long before mechanical fatigue affects anything else.